# Micronaut java httpclient creation with the existing server

Tags: java, server, micronaut, micronaut-client

I have a Micronaut application running with the below configuration:

```
micronaut:
  server:
    cors:
       enabled: true 
    port: 8080
```

Now I have an enhancement where I want to call a 3rd party URL and get the response in my application (one of the module in my application). I used the below code snippet:

```java
    EmbeddedServer server = ApplicationContext.run(EmbeddedServer.class);
    HttpClient client = server .getApplicationContext() .createBean(HttpClient.class, server.getURL());
    HttpRequest req = HttpRequest.GET(urlHost);
    HttpResponse<String> response = client.toBlocking().exchange(req, String.class);
```

But this is not working. I get port already in use. I did not find much help in google because Micronaut's `HttpClient` is usually used in Micronaut Test which is not in my case. Is this possible to use it in my application? If so how? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: FYI... Your CORS config doesn't have anything to do with the port already in use issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are starting another server by `ApplicationContext.run(EmbeddedServer.class)`.

You don't need it. It is enough to inject `HttpClient` into your class by constructor:

```java
@Singleton 
public class MyClient {

    private final RxHttpClient client;

    public MyClient(@Client("https://some.third-party.com") RxHttpClient client) {  
        this.client = client;
    }

    HttpResponse<String> getSomething(Integer id) {
        URI uri = UriBuilder.of("/some-objects").path(id).build();
        return client.toBlocking().exchange(HttpRequest.GET(uri), String.class);
    }
}
```

If you have third-party server URL in application configuration under `some-service.url` path for example, then you can use `@Client("${some-service.url}")`

---

Another option is to define declarative client for the third-party server and then inject it in your classes where needed.

First define client interface for your third-party service:

```java
@Client("some-service")
public interface SomeServiceClient {

    @Get("/api/some-objects/{id}")
    String getSomeObject(@QueryValue("id") Integer id);
}
```

Add client configuration for that service in application configuration (*application.yaml*):

```yaml
micronaut:
  http:
    services:
      some-service:
        url: "https://some.third-party.com"
        read-timeout: 1m
```

And then you can inject the `SomeServiceClient` where you need it:

```java
@Singleton 
public class SomeServiceConsumer {

    private final SomeServiceClient client;

    public SomeServiceConsumer(SomeServiceClient client) {  
        this.client = client;
    }

    void doWithSomething(Integer id) {
        String object = client.getSomeObject(id);
        ... // processing of object here
    }
}
```

You can find more information in a Micronaut documentation
https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-http-client-gradle-java.html